# How can I place model-functions in a separate file to be able to do something like user.isAdmin() from any component instead of userIsAdmin(user)?

Tags: angular, ionic3

What's on my mind:

**`User.ts`**

```
export interface User
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    level: number;
}
```

**`home.component.ts`**

```
import { User } from 'models/User';

@Component({ selector: 'app-home',
             templateUrl: './home.component.html' )}

export class HomeComponent {

user: User;

constructor() {}

userIsAdmin(user: User)
{
  return user.level === 1
}
```

**`home.component.html`**

```
<i class="delete" *ngIf="userIsAdmin(user)"></i>
```

With this approach, my home will be populated with too many model-related functions that I will need to separately define in all the components. I can place all the functions in a service and inject them on all components but I still won't be able to do `user.isAdmin()`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a decorator?

```js
function isAdmin(construct) { 
    construct.prototype.isAdmin = function () {

        return this.roles.includes('admin');
    }
}

@isAdmin
class User {
    roles: string[] = ['admin'];
}



console.log('isAdmin?', (new User).isAdmin())
```

Answer (score 1):

> Create AuthService for storing isAdmin and inject in every component
>   when u need.

**AuthService**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
private isAdmin: boolean;

  get isAdmin(): boolean {
        return this.isAdmin;
    }
  setIsAdmin(level: boolean): void{
       this.isAdmin = level
  }
}
```

**when you get user that time set a user is admin or not using `setIsAdmin` method.**

```
// write this function in that service when you get user.
```

like: `this.authService.setAdmin(user.level===1?true:false);`

// Component

```
export class UserComponent{
  constructor(public auth: AuthService){}
}
```

you can access in html this.auth.isAdmin.

**for example** `<i class="delete" *ngIf="this.auth.isAdmin"></i>`

also you can create variable into component and used it.

// write into onNgInit() method
this.isAdmin = this.auth.isAdmin;

**for example** `<i class="delete" *ngIf="isAdmin"></i>`